# Changing speed of a stepper motor break the rotation smoothness?

Tags: node.js, wiringpi

I'm using [node-stepper-wiringpi](https://github.com/nkolban/node-stepper-wiringpi)  with the L298N driver (12V) to control a [stepper motor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGFAF.jpg).

If i put a speed of 30 the rotation is smooth but if i put more than 30 the stepper struggle to make the rotation and even go backward a few miliseconds..

```js
var stepperWiringPi = require("../src/stepper-wiringpi");
var pinIN1 = 13;  // Stepper Red
var pinIN2 = 5;  // Stepper Blue
var pinIN3 = 6 ;// Stepper Green
var pinIN4 = 19; // Stepper Black

var motor1 = stepperWiringPi.setup(200, pinIN1, pinIN2, pinIN3, pinIN4);
var direction = 1;
console.log("Globals: FORWARD=%d, BACKWARD=%d", stepperWiringPi.FORWARD, stepperWiringPi.BACKWARD);
motor1.halt();

function changeDirection() {
  console.log("Changing direction from %d", direction);
  if (direction == stepperWiringPi.FORWARD) {
    direction = stepperWiringPi.BACKWARD;
    motor1.backward();
  } else {
    direction = stepperWiringPi.FORWARD;
    motor1.forward();
  }
  setTimeout(changeDirection.bind(this), 5000);
}

motor1.halt();



setTimeout(function() {


  motor1.setSpeed(30);

  changeDirection();

},2000);
```

Stepper motor datasheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGFAF.jpg

Console output when running the script:

```
stepMotor: isDigital=0, stepDelay=10, stepPin=NaN, directionPin=NaN
stepMotor: isDigital=0, stepDelay=10, stepPin=NaN, directionPin=NaN
stepMotor: isDigital=0, stepDelay=10, stepPin=NaN, directionPin=NaN
stepMotor: isDigital=0, stepDelay=10, stepPin=NaN, directionPin=NaN
```

Comment: anyone can help me?